# Unable to connect to remote MySQL from Cypress test running in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: mysql, cypress, gitlab-ci

Im have a simple test in Cypress, that uses the mysql package to read some data form a remote database. The test runs just fine locally, but fails to connect to DB when running in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. It shows this error in the stdout:
CypressError: `cy.task('queryDatabase')` failed with the following error:

> connect ETIMEDOUT

> From Node.js Internals:
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
> at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/builds/tests/cypress/cy-let/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:409:13)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:562:8)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

The connection itself is provided by cy.task defined in cypress.config.js file:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress")
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connections = {
  beta: {
    host: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    user: 'XXXXXX',
    password: XXXXXXXXXX',
    database: 'XXXXXXXXX'
  },
  production: {
    host: 'YYYYYYYYYY',
    user: 'YYYYY',
    password: 'YYYYY',
    database: 'YYYYY'
  }
}

// querying the database from Node
function queryDB(connectionInfo, query) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionInfo)
  connection.connect()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      }
      connection.end()
      return resolve(results)
    })
  })
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        queryDatabase({ dbName, query }) {
          const connectionInfo = connections[dbName]
          if (!connectionInfo) {
            throw new Error(`Do not have DB connection under name ${dbName}`)
          }
          return queryDB(connectionInfo, query)
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

What could be the problem? Any tips on how to find the cause?

Comment: where is this DB to which you are trying to connect

Comment: @Origin: It´s hosted on multiple servers accessible only through VPN. That leads me to a guestion wether node.js running in Gitlab can reach the server. I will try to ping the host from inside the Gitlab pipeline.

Comment: if its working in ur local and its hosted outside probably as u said could be from the job its not able to access ur db server. Also if its just for testing why not run the db as a service in the job itself